# Swift: Dismiss ViewController without keyboard slider

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiresponder

I present/dismiss ViewController with TextField like a fade. And keyboard do not need to slide on/out of the screen.
For presenting i did that by:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

How can i do that for dismiss?
It should not move somehow, i fade out VC and it should fade out with it as well. But insted of that it's moving down

Answer (score 0):

You trying to achive an UI effect which is doesn't comply to Human Interface Guidelines. This usualy means that you you have to find out an trick or a hack to achive it.